# Custumizing the test-network in HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm new at HyperLedger Fabric and trying to customize the test-network provided in the demo https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/test-network.
I can't find a way to 1. add new users and peers to the docker network and 2. create private channels using the CLI or Java SDK.
Could someone please help me ? A good tutorial to start would also be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Test Network with new orderer and peer, we need to extend fabric key with cryptogen, update system-channel definition, compose orderer nodes, compose peer nodes, join application channel and deploy the chaincode.

I created an article about how to extend test-network (in more details) with new peers and orderers https://dev.to/bukhorimuhammad/extending-fabric-2-test-network-50ll hope that helps